# How much money has been raised for needy children in Uganda from Vim?

Tags: history-of

As it says under [`:help iccf`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/uganda.txt.html)…

> Vim is Charityware.  You can use and copy it as much as you like, but
>   you are encouraged to make a donation for needy children in Uganda. 
>   Please see [`kcc`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/uganda.txt.html#kcc) below or visit the ICCF web site, available at these URLs:
>
> - http://iccf-holland.org/
> - http://www.vim.org/iccf/
> - http://www.iccf.nl/
>
> You can also sponsor the development of Vim.  Vim sponsors can vote
>   for features.  See [`sponsor`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/sponsor.txt.html#sponsor).  The money goes to Uganda anyway.

Is there any estimate of how much money has been raised for Uganda thanks to Vim?

I understand that an exact number is unobtainable, since donations are not always annotated with the reason. An upper/lower bound or order-of-magnitude figure will do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with text-editing using vim http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/questions/157/why-was-how-much-money-has-been-raised-for-needy-children-in-uganda-from-vim-c/161#161

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, while the charity-ware aspect of Vim is nice, it doesn't really seem to fit with what the help center lists as appropriate.

Answer (score 52):

tl;dr: as of 2022, it would seem that about €1.6 million has been raised.

ICCF & Vim seem very intertwined, and *probably* a majority of the donations
came from Vim users, but there is no way *anyone* can be certain about this.

---

The ICCF has published [financial reports](http://www.iccf.nl/iccf.html), summing up the numbers:

```
'94-'96   €     5 000 (estimate)

1997      €     7 241 (ƒ15 958)
1998      €    10 010 (ƒ22 060)
1999      €    15 122 (ƒ33 326)
2000      €    17 333 (ƒ38 198)
2001      €    26 441
2002      €    29 258
2003      €    28 625
2004      €    29 262
2005      €    36 937
2006      €    46 163
2007      €    47 688
2008      €    46 050
2009      €    50 309
2010      €    47 297
2011      €    54 790
2012      €    50 150
2013      €    55 595
2014      €    73 350
2015      €    68 872
2016      €    62 558
2017      €    65 562
2018      €    69 790
2019      €    78 147
2020      €    84 892
2021      €   119 078 

2002 .de  €    10 140 (estimate)
2003 .de  €     9 920 (estimate)
2004 .de  €    10 140 (estimate)
2005 .de  €    12 799 (estimate)
2006 .de  €    15 995 (estimate)
2007 .de  €    16 523 (estimate)
2008 .de  €    15 955 (estimate)
2009 .de  €    17 430 (estimate)
2010 .de  €    16 386 (estimate)
2011 .de  €    18 981 (estimate)
2012 .de  €    17 373 (estimate)
2013 .de  €    19 259 (estimate)
2014 .de  €    25 421 (estimate)
2015 .de  €    23 867 (estimate)
2016 .de  €    21 679 (estimate)
2017 .de  €    22 720 (estimate)
2018 .de  €    24 185 (estimate)
2019 .de  €    27 081 (estimate)
2020 .de  €    29 418 (estimate)
2021 .de  €    41 264 (estimate)
Total .de €   396 536 (estimate)

Total     € 1 622 056
```

The German donations are mentioned separately; the 2002 report mentions:

> Most sponsors and donors from Germany started paying through MISEREOR in 2002.
> This gives them a tax advantage. In 2002 about 10 140 euro has been received by
> MISEREOR. This money goes directly to the project and can therefore not be found
> in the ICCF Holland figures. When adding MISEREOR to the total amount that
> sponsors and donors have contributed towards the project, the increase is almost
> 50%.

And the report from 2003 and onwards either don't mention a figure, or mention a
figure of "more than 10 000". I've grown this amount with the same amount as the
other donations for 2003 and onwards, which should give a reasonable-ish
estimate. [Bram has mentioned these are slightly too
high](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/ifBJbw72Itc) after I
announced that about a million Euro had been raised:

> The estimate for the German donations are a bit too high though.  Last
> year [2016] was about 16 000 euro.

---

So how long has Vim been involved with ICCF? The oldest version of Vim I've been
able to find if Vim 3.0 from March 1996 ([here](http://vim.mirror.fr/unix/));
this already has the "charityware" license, in the `uganda.txt` it says:

> Summer 1993 I spent one month in Uganda with a Dutch team. I was very
> impressed with what I experienced there. Together with local people we built a
> nursery school in Kibaale. In only three weeks from nothing to a roofed
> building!
>
> [..]
>
> The work is very well organized. Every dollar is spent on something useful.
> Our team brought about $2000.
>
> [..]
>
> How do you know that the money will be spent right? First of all you have my
> personal guarantee as the author of Vim. Further the project is co-sponsored
> and inspected by World Vision, Save the Children Fund and International Child
> Care Fund. I will work for the project as a volunteer from September 1994 to
> August 1995.

I don't have the figures from 1994 to 1996; based on the above figures, I'll add
an estimate of €5 000 for these 2 years.

So how much of this money comes from Vim users? All the financial reports have a
statement similar to this one:

> Donations have been received for the use of Vim, but this is not mentioned
> separately, because it is not always clear if a donation was because of using
> Vim.

This makes sense. I once did a (one-time) donation to ICCF, and just transferred
some money to the bank account; there is no way to know that I donated because I
use Vim and read about Uganda there.

The announcement of the [2014 financial report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/2czE8NAWetM) also mentions:

> I am very glad to see the amount has gone up quite a bit.  Mostly because of
> one-time donations.  I'm not sure this is because of Vim users, but I expect
> so

Vim does keep a "[hall of honours](http://www.vim.org/sponsor/hall_of_honour.php)" of people who donated more than €100;
however, this list is probably *very* incomplete as well. The total amount
listed here is about €25 000. But for many people the donation amount is
concealed, and there are probably many more who aren't listed at all. So for the
purpose of this question, it's not very useful.